# Why ViewBag.SomeProperty doesn't throw an exception when the property is not exists?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

In `MVC`, sometimes I'm setting specific property of `ViewBag` according to some condition.For example:

```
if(someCondition)
{
   // do some work
   ViewBag.SomeProperty = values;
}

return View();
```

In my `View` I'm checking whether the property is null like this:

```
@if(ViewBag.SomeProperty != null)
{
   ...
}
```

Until now I was thinking that should throw an *exception* because if my condition is not satisfied then `SomeProperty` is never get set.And that's why I was always using an `else` statement to set that property to `null`.But I just noticed, it **doesn't** throw an *exception* even if the property doesn't exists.For example in a `Console Application` if I do the following, I'm getting a `RuntimeBinderException`:

```
dynamic dynamicVariable = new {Name = "Foo"};

if(dynamicVariable.Surname != null) Console.WriteLine(dynamicVariable.Surname);
```

But it doesn't happen when it comes to `ViewBag`.What's the *difference* ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AFAIK the `ViewBag` is a dynamic wrapper around `ViewData`. And `ViewData` itself retrieves the values as follows:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        object value;
        _innerDictionary.TryGetValue(key, out value);
        return value;
    }
    set { _innerDictionary[key] = value; }
}
```

hence, if key doesn't exist it returns default value for type and doesn't throw exception.

Answer (score 1):

ViewBag inherits from DynamicViewDataDictionary which returns null for missing properties.